# Should I specialize or overload?

Tags: c++, templates, function, overloading, template-specialization

Suppose I have a function template:

```
template <typename T>
std::string foo(const T& x)
{
    return some_computation_involving(x);
}
```

If `x` is already a string, I just want to pass it back verbatim. Should I specialize the function template?

```
template <>
std::string foo(const std::string& x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Or should I provide a non-template function?

```
std::string foo(const std::string& x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Under what circumstances should I choose which option, and what are the pitfalls I need to be aware of?

Comment: I believe the important pitfall to avoid is having both specializations and overloads as the overload will trump and ignore specialization.

Comment: would you not be calling the method like foo<std::string>(arg)? in that case why even call the method if you know it is a string?

Comment: @Sriram: not generally. The template parameter can be infered from the argument. Additionally, consider calling the routine from a templated function... `foo<T>(arg)` might or might not be passed a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specialize Function Templates vs Function Overload vs Class Specializing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994949/specialize-function-templates-vs-function-overload-vs-class-specializing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefer overload over function specialization, says **Herb Sutter**. He explains this in his articles:

- [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)
- [Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Always choose an overload if you can. Function template specialization is a fickle bitch. For example, no implicit conversions are considered, including covariance, when deciding about specializations.

Edit: For example, if you do something like,

```
template<typename T> void func(T t);
template<> void func(base*);

int main() {
    func(new derived);
}
```

The specialization will not be called. If it were an overload, it would be called.

Comment: Could you expand on the covariance issue?

Comment: I think *covariance* is not the proper term here... *inheritance* would be a better one.

Comment: Are you sure the overload would be called? According to [ideone](http://ideone.com/OA22W) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7765562/20984), I'm not so sure anymore.