# Overriding a templated function with a polymorphic one

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, template-specialization

If I have

```
template<class T>
TalkyBuffer& operator<<(T const &object) { // Template
...
}
TalkyBuffer& operator<<(TalkySerialisable const &object); // Override
```

and a class

```
class A : public TalkySerialisable {
...}
```

Then if I perform

```
TalkyBuffer b;
A test;
b << test;
```

Then gcc is calling the Template function rather than the Override function

However if I specifically define an override

```
TalkyBuffer& operator<<(A const &object); // Override without polymorphism
```

Then gcc picks that one.
Is there a practical way to override a templated function with an abstract class?

I read this but it doesn't shed light onto what happens when you throw polymorphism into the mix:
http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm
Also I couldn't find a solution here but perhaps I'm using the wrong terms.

Comment: `b << *static_cast<TalkySerialisable*>(&test)` does this work?

Answer (score 1):

When defining the function `TalkyBuffer& operator<<(TalkySerialisable const &object);` You are not overriding. You are overloading the tmeplated function.

But, when the complier sees `b << test;`, it searches for an operator that wants an `A`. It has one, it's the templated function that requires no automatic cast. This is the best choice.

The overloaded function requires an automatic cast (from A to TalkySerialisable) on the parameters to fit the declaration, and is not the best choice.

Comment: Yes he is overloading and not specializing. `template<> TalkyBuffer& operator<< <>(TalkySerializable const & object);` would be a specialization.

Comment: I agree with Luc. Without `template<>` i'm overriding. However your point about functions that do not 'require a cast' taking priority is certainly interesting and explains this phenomenon. I'm wondering is there any way around this whilst retaining something equivalent to the generic `TalkyBuffer& operator<<(T const &object)`

Comment: @Elliot: well, to be exact, you are not *overriding* but *overloading*. Overriding is about virtual methods (dynamic polymorphism) while overloading is about having several functions with the same name and different parameters (which is another type of polymorphism, but happens at compile-time).

Comment: @Luc: Thanks for the precise wording. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to use a simple `function` based solution, reusing function overload for derivation.

```
struct specialized {};
struct generic {};

template <class T>
TalkyBuffer& serialize(TalkyBuffer& buffer, T const& object, generic) {
  ...
}

generic dispatch(...) {} // always picked up last in overload resolution

template <class T>
TalkyBuffer& TalkyBuffer::operator<<(T const& object) { // Template
  return serialize(*this, object, dispatch(object));
}
```

Now, let's implement your custom class:

```
TalkyBuffer& serialize(TalkyBuffer& buffer,
                       TalkySerialisable const& object,
                       specialized);

specialized dispatch(TalkySerialisable const&) {}
```

And create a derived one:

```
class A: public TalkySerialisable {};
```

So, what happens ?

- `TalkyBuffer::operator<<(T const&)` will be picked up
- when trying to resolve the overload for `serialize`, it will first compute the result of `dispatch`
- when resolving the result of `dispatch`, `dispatch(TalkySerializable const&)` is a better match than `dispath(...)`, thus the return type is `specialized`
- the generic `serialize` cannot be used (there is no conversion from `specialized` to `generic`), so inheritance kicks in

Comment: Nice, using overloaded function to obtain the tag for dispatching is much better than type traits because it works seamlessly with inheritance and implicit conversions.

Comment: @LucTouraille: I only wish I could make it less clumsy, but if I try replacing the `generic` argument in `serialize` directly with `...` I get an ambiguous overload :x

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`Boost.enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html):

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>

template<typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<
    boost::is_base_of<TalkySerializable, T>,
    TalkyBuffer &
>::type operator<<(T const & object) { // Template for non TalkySerializable
...
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<
    boost::is_base_of<TalkySerializable, T>,
    TalkyBuffer &
>::type operator<<(T const & object); // Template overload for TalkySerializable

...

TalkyBuffer b;
A test;
b << test; // calls operator<< <A>(A const &), which instantiates 
           // the overload for TalkySerializable
b << 41; // calls operator<< <int>(int const &), which corresponds to
         // the "default" overload
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but I failed to find a better one: specializing the template does not work either.

---

As @Matthieu noted in the comment, the previous solution has the major drawback that the base template needs to know that it will be overloaded, which is an unnecessary coupling that hinders extensibility.

To solve this problem, I came up with a new approach using [tag dispatching](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching), along with trait classes and compile-time introspection using [Boost.MPL macros](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/introspection.html).

```
// TalkyBuffer.hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/has_xxx.hpp>

// defines a metafunction has_talky_buffer_tag<T> that allows us to know at
// compile-time if T has a member type named talky_buffer_tag
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(talky_buffer_tag)

// tag for the default case
struct default_talky_buffer_tag {};

// trait class for obtaining the tag of a type
template <typename T, typename Enable = void >
struct talky_buffer_trait
{
    typedef default_talky_buffer_tag type;
};

// specialization for types that provide a nested typedef
template <typename T>
struct talky_buffer_trait<T, 
    typename boost::enable_if<has_talky_buffer_tag<T> >::type>
{
    typedef typename T::talky_buffer_tag type;
};


struct TalkyBuffer 
{
    // Insertion operator, which calls an implementation function that can
    // be overloaded depending on the tag
    template<typename T>
    TalkyBuffer & operator<<(T const & object) 
    {
        typename talky_buffer_trait<T>::type tag;
        return insertionOperatorImpl(*this, object, tag);
    }
};

// default implementation
template <typename T>
TalkyBuffer & insertionOperatorImpl(TalkyBuffer & buf, T const & object,
    default_talky_buffer_tag)
{
    std::cout << "default";
    return buf;
}


//-------
// TalkySerializable.hpp

struct TalkySerializable 
{ 
    struct tag {}; 
    typedef tag talky_buffer_tag; 
};

// A inherits from the nested typedef
struct A : public TalkySerializable {};

// implementation for TalkySerializable objects
template <typename Serializable>
TalkyBuffer & insertionOperatorImpl(TalkyBuffer & buf, Serializable const & object,
    TalkySerializable::tag)
{
    std::cout << "specialized";
    return buf;
}


//-------
int main()
{
    TalkyBuffer b;
    A test;
    b << test; // outputs "specialized"
    b << 41;   // outputs "default"
}
```

To provide new implementations of the insertion operator for a given type `T`, one needs to provide a new type to act as a tag (`TypeSerializable::tag` in our example), provides a way to associate `T` with the new tag (either by using a nested typedef as in the example, or by specializing the trait class: `template <> talky_buffer_trait<T> { typedef new_tag type };`), and finally overload the implementation function (`insertionOperatorImpl` in the example).

Comment: I would prefer a less invasive way. Capacity detections or traits would allow the base template to be agnostic of the types for which specializations exist.

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, the fact that the base template has to know that there are overloads is bothering me as well. I'll try to come up with a better solution.

Comment: @Matthieu: the problem is that templates and inheritance often works pretty badly together. For example, if I wanted to use a trait class, I wouldn't be able to specialize it for all `TalkySerializable`, since `trait<A>` would not match the specialization. This is an issue I often stumbled upon, and always fixed with workarounds that did not completely satisfied me, so if you have some insights on this subject, I'll be glad to hear them!

Comment: @Matthieu: I added another solution using tag dispatching to reduce coupling, feel free to share your thoughts on this other approach.

Comment: I don't know of any system that works without the base template provisionning for overload, what I am afraid of is the reverse dependency :)